# How to receive and display Message from MQTT server to your Table View

Tags: ios, objective-c, mqtt, messagebroker

i have an app that sends and receive data message using terminal in MQTT server. what i want to do is create a Table View and display the Messages from the server. how do i do that ? This is my codes. you can use this code if you like .Just Download a Libraries of MQTT in PAHO. just search PAHO . thank you in advance !

This Code for this button is for Connection to the Broker "MQTT" Connections

```
- (IBAction)brokerButtonPressed:(RLYButton*)sender

    int status;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    __weak ViewController* weakSelf = self;

    if (_mqttClient == NULL)
    {
        if (!_brokerField.text.length || !_mqttClientID.length) { return; }

        status = MQTTAsync_create(&_mqttClient, _brokerField.text.UTF8String, _mqttClientID.UTF8String, MQTTCLIENT_PERSISTENCE_NONE, NULL);
        if (status != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) { return; }

        status = MQTTAsync_setCallbacks(_mqttClient, (__bridge void*)weakSelf, mqttConnectionLost, mqttMessageArrived, NULL);
        if (status != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) { mqttDestroy((__bridge void*)weakSelf); }

        MQTTAsync_connectOptions connOptions = MQTTAsync_connectOptions_initializer;
        connOptions.onSuccess = mqttConnectionSucceeded;
        connOptions.onFailure = mqttConnectionFailed;
        connOptions.context = (__bridge void*)weakSelf;

        _brokerField.enabled = NO;
        [_brokerButton setTitle:@"Connecting" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        _brokerButton.enabled = NO;

        status = MQTTAsync_connect(_mqttClient, &connOptions);
        if (status != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) { mqttDestroy((__bridge void*)weakSelf); }



        {UIAlertView * alertView;
            alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"MQTT Connection to broker Succeeded!" message:@" Press OK to continue" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];


            [alertView show]; }



    }
    else
    {
        _brokerField.enabled = NO;
        [_brokerButton setTitle:@"Disconnecting" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        _brokerButton.enabled = NO;
        _dataView.hidden = YES;

        MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions disconnOptions = MQTTAsync_disconnectOptions_initializer;
        disconnOptions.onSuccess = mqttDisconnectionSucceeded;
        disconnOptions.onFailure = mqttDisconnectionFailed;
        disconnOptions.context = (__bridge void*)weakSelf;
        status = MQTTAsync_disconnect(_mqttClient, &disconnOptions);
    }
}
```

This is a press button for Subscriber/Topic

```
    - (IBAction)subscribeButtonPressed:(RLYButton*)sender

    if (_mqttClient==NULL) { return; }
    if (!_subscriptionField.text.length) { printf("You need to write a subscription topic.\n"); return; }

    int status;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    __weak ViewController* weakSelf = self;

    if ([[_subscriptionButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqualToString:@"Subscribe"])
    {   // When the button is pressed, you want to subscribe.
        _subscriptionField.enabled = NO;
        [_subscriptionButton setTitle:@"Subscribing" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        _subscriptionButton.enabled = NO;

        MQTTAsync_responseOptions subOptions = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
        subOptions.onSuccess = mqttSubscriptionSucceeded;
        subOptions.onFailure = mqttSubscriptionFailed;
        subOptions.context = (__bridge void*)weakSelf;
        status = MQTTAsync_subscribe(_mqttClient, _subscriptionField.text.UTF8String, 0, &subOptions);
        if (status != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) { _subscriptionButton.enabled = YES; }
    }
    else
    {   // When the button is pressed, you want to unsubscribe
        [_subscriptionButton setTitle:@"Unsubscribing" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        _subscriptionButton.enabled = NO;

        MQTTAsync_responseOptions unsubOptions = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
        unsubOptions.onSuccess = mqttUnsubscriptionSucceeded;
        unsubOptions.onFailure = mqttUnsubscriptionFailed;
        unsubOptions.context = (__bridge void*)weakSelf;
        status = MQTTAsync_unsubscribe(_mqttClient, _subscriptionField.text.UTF8String, &unsubOptions);
        if (status != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) { _subscriptionField.enabled = YES; _subscriptionButton.enabled = YES; }
    }
}
```

This is button for publish a message to another User

```
    - (IBAction)publishButtonPressed:(RLYButton*)sender

    if (_mqttClient==NULL) { return; }
    if (!_publishField.text.length) { printf("You need to write a publish topic.\n"); return; }
    if (!_publishBodyField.text.length) { printf("You need to to write a message to be published.\n"); return; }

    __weak ViewController* weakSelf = self;
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    MQTTAsync_message message = MQTTAsync_message_initializer;
    message.payloadlen = (int)[_publishBodyField.text lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] + 1;
    char payload[message.payloadlen];
    [_publishBodyField.text getCString:payload maxLength:message.payloadlen encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    message.payload = payload;

    _publishButton.enabled = NO;
    _publishField.enabled = NO;

    MQTTAsync_responseOptions pubOptions = MQTTAsync_responseOptions_initializer;
    pubOptions.onSuccess = mqttPublishSucceeded;
    pubOptions.onFailure = mqttPublishFailed;
    pubOptions.context = (__bridge void*)weakSelf;
    int status = MQTTAsync_sendMessage(_mqttClient, _publishField.text.UTF8String, &message, &pubOptions);
    if (!status != MQTTASYNC_SUCCESS) { _publishField.enabled = YES; _publishButton.enabled = YES; }
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me to do the display of message to UI Table view from the MQTT server ? i would please to know how . thank you !